# Validadores dentro de condicion negada javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con una condicion que realice en javascript, mando a llamar id's con una condicion negada, si todos los inputs son diferente a vacio, entonces guarda los datos en la base de datos, sin embargo hay unos casos en los que aplico expresiones regulares, por lo cual la condicion en algunos id ya no tienen que ser negados, si no iguales, pero lo hago y no almacena los datos, quisiera saber una forma de hacerlo, gracias.

**Javascript**

```
                case "UpdatePerfil":
                    {
                        if (document.getElementById('Perfil_Nombre').value != "" &&
                            document.getElementById('Perfil_ApellidoPaterno').value != "" &&
                            document.getElementById('Perfil_FechaNacimiento').value != "" &&
                            document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Sexo').value != "" &&
                            document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Pais').value != "" &&
                            document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Estado').value != "" &&     

            document.getElementById('Perfil_RFC').value != "" &&
                document.getElementById('Perfil_RFC').value == /^([a-zA-

Z&Ññ]{3}|[a-zA-Z][aeiouAEIOU][a-zA-Z]{2})\d{2}((01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3

[01])|02(0[1-9]|[12]\d)|(04|06|09|11)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9Aa])?$/) {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares se comparan con diferentes métodos pero no con `==` o `!=`. En tu caso podrías usar esto:

```
var exp = /tuexpresionregular/;
if (exp.test(document.getElementById("tuid"))){}
```

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) tienes más información.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comentan arriba hay que aplicar la función test de la expresión regular para comprobar si se cumple o no, esta función devuelve true/false.
Viendo el tamaño del if, no sería mala idea sacarlo a una función para modificaciones futuras.

```
var regExp = /^([a-zA-Z&Ññ]{3}|[a-zA-Z][aeiouAEIOU][a-zA-Z]{2})\d{2}((01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|02(0[1-9]|[12]\d)|(04|06|09|11)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30))([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9Aa])?$/;

...    

case "UpdatePerfil":
    if (document.getElementById('Perfil_Nombre').value &&
        document.getElementById('Perfil_ApellidoPaterno').value &&
        document.getElementById('Perfil_FechaNacimiento').value &&
        document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Sexo').value &&
        document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Pais').value &&
        document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Estado').value &&     
        document.getElementById('Perfil_RFC').value &&
        regExp.test(document.getElementById('Perfil_RFC').value)) {
```